# Using variables inside a string in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to build a regex match with variables as part of the matched string:

```
var_a := 'somestring'
var_b := 'someotherstring'

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE some_field ~* 'var_a.+?(?=\-)\-var_b)')
```

How do I insert the variables into the string? Like in js you can simply do:

```
`${var_a} restofstring`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function:

```
WHERE some_field ~* format('%s.+?(?=\-)\-%s)', var_a, var_b)
```

Comment: I've just managed to do the same thing (before reading your answer) like so: ~*(var_a||'.+?'||var_b) It seems to work. Is it also acceptable or should I use the format function with % for the vars?

Comment: @S.Schenk: I find solutions using format() way easier to read and maintain compared to the equivalent using `||`. But that's largely personal taste. But it becomes "mandatory" if it's used to generate dynamic SQL.

Comment: It's mandatory when used for dynamic sql to prevent sql injections right?

Comment: That's one of the reasons, yes. I wrote "mandatory" in the sense that it's the only sane option where the base SQL is still readable.